# Div not maintaining a 1/1 aspect ratio when height is calculated dynamically

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create the following CSS layout using flexbox:

[image]

Imagine the layout as a flex row, with one box on the left (the image) and to the right a flex column with all the text stacked on top of each other. The height of the box on the left automatically scaled to the height of the flex column to the right. I have gone up to this point so far, but I have been unable to get it into a square shape (as in the width is the same as the height).

Currently I have the code which produces the following result:

```css
.container {
  background: orange;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.profile_pic {
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  background: blue;
}

.text_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="profile_pic"></div>

  <div class="text_container">
    <h1>Name: Toby</h1>
    <h2>Gender: Male</h2>
    <h3>Password: 123</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

There is meant to be a square shaped blue box on the left of column which contains the text but it's not showing for some reason?

If I set a specific width, it does show, but this is not what I want as I wish for the width to be the same as the height (maintain a 1/1 aspect ratio):

[image]

My current 'workaround' is wrapping the blue box in a flex with `align-items` set to `center`, and then making the blue box a hard coded size which roughly matches the height of the box:

[image]

I see lots of such similar layouts, for example the YouTube channel thing:

[image]

Stack Overflow indicator:

[image]

I believe such similar layouts are done by using workarounds such as setting an explicit height for the container or the image itself. This approach isn't fine as there is always a small margin of error, and if I want to remove a line from the column flex to the right, I will need to manually adjust the sizes (it's not dynamic).

Comment: Where is the `Flex` component from?

Comment: @Unmitigated Hey, it's a ChakraUI React component, just think of it has a regular div with `display: flex` :) Hopefully that's not too distracting! If it is, I'm happy to translate it to raw HTML/CSS.

Comment: Can you please update your **question tags** as well by adding `reactjs`? Also, to possibly get more answers I think it would be better to convert it into **HTML/CSS** to finally get a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Ferris this is not specifically related to React, I don't want to get punished for posting off-topic stuff. I'll do my best to convert this to raw HTML/CSS now.

Comment: @Unmitigated Thanks for your interest, my expected result is that the width of the blue box should be the same as it's calculated height (which should be the same height as the column which contains the text) -- the box should maintain a 1/1 aspect ratio. I drew an image above, attempting to illustrate my desired result (although it isn't in color). Hopefully that's clear enough.

Comment: I'm thinking that the only way around this might indeed be having to set an explicit height for the container itself, it's not something I want to do though as I wish for the height to be dynamically calculated based on the column with the headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me hours for this, I just thought it's supposed to be simple but I couldn't find the solution sooner. So after tweaking with flexbox, relative-absolute position, and even table layout, I just realized that we can use grid instead to achieve this. The most important thing in here is the `min-height: 100%` and `height: 0` on the first child. The `height` must be zero so that it's prevented from the grid height calculation, and the `min-height` is so that it's 100% of row's height:

```css
.container {
  background: orange;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

.profile_pic {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 0;
  background: blue;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}

.text_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="profile_pic">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/2">
  </div>

  <div class="text_container">
    <h1>Name: Toby</h1>
    <h2>Gender: Male</h2>
    <h3>Password: 123</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
```

You can change the image to something with a not 1/1 ratio, and you'll see that it will stay in 1/1 ratio.

Comment: hope css makes such layout easier in future !

Comment: This is not a one-size-fits-all solution, as it will not work if the image is smaller height than the content

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't test it on smaller image, is it now?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be solved with CSS if you want to be as flexible as possible with regard to the height. But a few lines of JavaScript can do the job. First determine the `height` of the outer container. Then assign the received value as `width` to the image container.

It might be an advantage to assign an `ID` to each element instead of working with classes, but just with the provided code I can't say that. However, you would then have to use `document.getElementById()` instead of `document.querySelector()`.

It should also be mentioned that `height` can be determined differently, depending on requirements:

**clientHeight** - height + padding *(currently in use)*
**offsetHeight** - height + padding + border

And others, but that would be too much for now.
Here's the snippet ...

```js
let containerHeight = document.querySelector('.container').clientHeight;
let imgContainerWidth = document.querySelector('.profile_pic');
imgContainerWidth.style.width = containerHeight + 'px';
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background: orange;
}

.profile_pic {
    margin-right: 30px;
    background: blue;
}

.text_container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="profile_pic"></div>
    <div class="text_container">
        <h1>Name: Toby</h1>
        <h2>Gender: Male</h2>
        <h3>Password: 123</h2>
    </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a potential solution. Initially, I considered utilizing JS/TS to address this matter; however, I have reservations about employing techniques that directly manipulate the user interface. (Perhaps an alternative approach could involve developing a reusable React component that automates this process.) In the event that I do not receive a response utilizing raw CSS or HTML, I will acknowledge your solution as the most beneficial one. Additionally, I express my appreciation for your contribution.

Comment: You're welcome. I would also be very interested in a purely CSS-based solution or whether it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Also, as an option, you can set `.profile_pic { writing-mode: vertical-lr; }`. `.container` must have `display: grid;`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  background: orange;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

.profile_pic {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: blue;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  position: relative;
}

.profile_pic img {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.text_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="profile_pic">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300">
  </div>
  <div class="text_container">
    <h1>Name: Toby</h1>
    <h2>Gender: Male</h2>
    <h3>Password: 123</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```html
.container {
  background: orange;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 300px;
  align-items: center;
}

.profile_pic {
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;

}

.text_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
height: 100%;
  
}
```

Try this out. In here you have to define a height value in the parent container.

Comment: You are setting the height explicitly, which is not what I am looking for.